# Consume Python DAO from cocoa/objective c front end

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa, dao, data-access-object

My plan is to develop a multi-tier, multi-platform database application.
I would like to consume the data from cocoa/objective c apps, .net apps, and web browsers.
I don’t really know where to start and have been looking a Python, but can’t find if cocoa/objective c apps can consume python data objects.
Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to achieve my goal?

My requirements are:

1. Data layer should be platform independent.
2. Whole system is scalable. Therefore multi tier.
3. Data access can be from cocoa, .net and web based clients.

Answer (score 0):

You can make python and objective-c work together.  Since you can use 100% normal C you can use the Python C interface.  It's very tedious though.

There's also [PyObjC](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/).  This acts as a bridge between Objective-C and Python.  The documentation is pretty good and it will be **much** simpler than using the Python C interface directly.

You could also try using [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/).  Thrift is like Protocol Buffers by Google, but has support for generating Objective-C classes.  You will have to write some boiler plate code to convert the data object into a thrift object; but after that is done you can pass information amongst any of the languages thrift supports.  Documentation is on the thin side; I wrote a tutorial on using with Objective-C available on the thrift wiki [here](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageObjectiveC) some time ago, not sure if it us up-to-date though as there have been several releases of thrift since then.